# Why are my these links running together? I'm using MVC and CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, https

I just opened up the project and switched the protocol to HTTPS, but now all the links in the navbar are messed up.  I've tried everything, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top navbar-expand-sm bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-expand-sm">
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my HTML code for the navbar, I've been playing around with it a bit but I can't get it to do anything different.  It just looks like this...

[Navbar Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOuN0.jpg)

I even tried to change some of the CSS, but nothing seems to help.  Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: did you check that all your CSS files loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was having trouble deciding what classes should be modified in CSS... I figured out that I could create a class like this `ul > .nav-item` and input some code for left and right padding, and it worked!